# Error "Token PropertyName in state ArrayStart would result in an invalid JSON object." when trying to serialize object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

This is the error

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoComplete(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.InternalWritePropertyName(string)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName(string)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.WriteTo(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Collections.IEnumerable, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, object, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter, System.Collections.IEnumerable, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty)
```

It's thrown in this method:

```
public static void SaveSystemScans()
{
     File.AppendAllText(StarSystemsDatabase, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(systemScans));
}
```

I'm working on a programm to deserialize Json data from a file from a game. In the game, you can scan Star Systems, each of with contains multiple Stellar Bodies. These stellar Bodies have multiple different properties, which are represented in the code as `JProperty`. I believe the error might be occuring somewhere in the List of JProperties in a Stellar Object. I've manually checked each Property though and they seem fine. I was able to find some other Question related to this error, however none of the conclusively answered why this error is thrown. (Most of them were about either the `dynamic` type or Azure, which I'm both not using. Right now I'm just trying to reserialize the main List into JSON to read it again and to build a library of systems. I'm eventually planning to put them into a database.

The object I'm trying to serialize looks like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, SystemScan> systemScans = new Dictionary<string, SystemScan>();
```

Each SystemScan object contains a name and a `List<StellarObjects>` with all the StellarObjects of a system.
The constructor for this class is fairly simple and looks like this:

```
public StellarObject(string jsonData)
{
      Properties = JObject.Parse(jsonData).Properties().ToList();
      BodyName = JObject.Parse(jsonData)["BodyName"].ToString();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is valid to post here, but this is what the primary List looks like at the time of the exception:

[image: The structure of the object with properties.]

Comment: Try using [`TraceWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/TraceWriter.htm) to diagnose what's fails and/or please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide a [mre], this problem is unlikely to be reconstructed from the parts shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to serialize a **list of properties**, which is not a construct supported by the [JSON standard](https://json.org/).  You will need to modify your `Properties` member to be something that can be serialized as well-formed JSON.

The specific exception can reproduced much more simply with the following code:

```
var jsonData = @"{""name"" : ""value""}";
var properties = JObject.Parse(jsonData).Properties().ToList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties);
```

This code parses a simple JSON object `{"name" : "value"}`, attempts to serialize its list of properties, and fails as shown in demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0hBIhu).

The reason this fails is that JSON only supports the following two container types ([link](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)):

> - An *object* is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` *left brace* and ends with `}` *right brace*. Each name is followed by `:` *colon* and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` *comma*.
> - An *array* is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` *left bracket* and ends with `]` *right bracket*. Values are separated by `,` *comma*.

However when you try to serialize a list of properties, it seems you are expecting to get some sort of hybrid container, viz. an array of name/value pairs `["name" : "value"]`.  Such a container is not supported by JSON, and so Json.NET throws the exception you see when you try to create one.

So, what are you options?

1. If you just want to embed the property **values**, use `PropertyValues`:

   ```
   var properties = JObject.Parse(jsonData).PropertyValues().ToList();
   ```

   This results in `["value"]`.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gb951b).
2. If you want to embed each property in its own object, do the following:

   ```
   var properties = JObject.Parse(jsonData).Properties()
       .Select(p => new JObject(p))
       .ToList();
   ```

   This results in `[{"name":"value"}]`.  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T4OEOo).
3. If you just want to embed the contents of `jsonData` unchanged, you may do so using [`JRaw`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm):

   ```
   var properties = new JRaw(jsonData);
   ```

   This results in the JSON being re-serialized unchanged.  Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjXbq0).
4. Alternatively, you may wrap the properties in a temporary `JObject` for serialization, like so:

   ```
   var properties = JObject.Parse(jsonData).Properties().ToList();
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JObject(properties));
   ```

   This also results in the original JSON being re-serialized unchanged.  Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rgTeMK).

Since you have already apparently committed to adding a `public List<JProperty> Properties { get; set; }` to your `StellarObject` data model (not shown in your question), the quickest fix might be to mark the property as ignored, and add a private serialization surrogate that wraps the list of properties in an object like so:

```
public partial class StellarObject
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<JProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Properties")]        
    JObject SerializableProperties
    {
        get { return new JObject(Properties); }
        set { Properties = value.Properties().ToList(); }
    }
}
```

Note that this data model results in `BodyName` being serialized **twice** -- once as `StellarObject.BodyName`, and once as a property inside `Properties`.  You may want to normalize your data to remove the duplication.

Demo fiddle #6 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8dUIwd).

Comment: Thank you very much for this incredibly detailed response. Code works as intended now.